# Spy window is pixelated

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I am trying to use spy to zoom in a plot that has a lot going on at different scales. However when I zoom in, the plot doesn't look as expected. It looks sort of pixelated.
Any idea why? And how to fix this?

The inner plot when zoomed in should look something like this [image: what zoom in should look like]

but instead it looks like this:
[image: what zoom in actually looks like]

Below is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={%
cells={anchor=west}}
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{>=stealth'}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\definecolor{m1_color}{HTML}{9BFF85}
\definecolor{m2_color}{HTML}{BC86D1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=100,
   width=3cm,height=4cm,connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[
  legend style = {at={(1.05,1.0)}, anchor=north west},
  ylabel = {$x_2$},
  title = {Sets},
  xlabel = {$x_1$},
  width=8cm, height=8cm
]

\addplot+[
  mark = {none},
  red, dashed
] coordinates {
  (-0.2617, -4000.0)
  (-0.2617, 4000.0)
};
\addlegendentry{{}{Set}}

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (1.2, 0.2)
  (1.0, 0.2)
  (1.0, -8.32667268468867e-17)
  (1.2, -8.32667268468867e-17)
  (1.2, 0.2)
};
\addlegendentry{{}{M1}}

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color
] coordinates {
  (1.2, 0.2)
  (1.0, 0.2)
  (1.0, -8.32667268468867e-17)
  (1.2, -8.32667268468867e-17)
  (1.2, 0.2)
};
\addlegendentry{{}{M2}}

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (1.0, -0.265972863900861)
  (1.0, -0.456228776570086)
  (1.2, -0.438084931713062)
  (1.22, -0.238084931713074)
  (1.22, -0.0478290190439142)
  (1.01999999999999, -0.0659728639009378)
  (1.0, -0.265972863900861)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (1.0000000000000002, -0.33518225819442576)
  (1.22, -0.33518225819442576)
  (1.22, -0.17021742804955514)
  (1.0000000000000002, -0.17021742804955514)
  (1.0000000000000002, -0.33518225819442576)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (0.954377122342992, -0.522007062932457)
  (0.954377122342992, -0.791111837889065)
  (1.17437712234299, -0.77154673115243)
  (1.21521709809561, -0.363146973626258)
  (1.21521709809561, -0.0940421986695393)
  (0.995217098095621, -0.113607305406173)
  (0.954377122342992, -0.522007062932457)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.9664817741805576, -0.5148584453878854)
  (1.2029782571950445, -0.5148584453878854)
  (1.2029782571950445, -0.3472697833820113)
  (0.9664817741805576, -0.3472697833820113)
  (0.9664817741805576, -0.5148584453878854)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (1.20581287822866, -0.383612590977629)
  (1.20581287822865, -0.0110938341341925)
  (0.944972902476051, -0.0354610929819111)
  (0.875265938554085, -0.732530732201572)
  (0.875265938554085, -1.10504948904487)
  (1.1361059143067, -1.08068223019715)
  (1.20581287822866, -0.383612590977629)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.9149959296417689, -0.6220770983026074)
  (1.1682512788568433, -0.6220770983026074)
  (1.1682512788568433, -0.44233041239025134)
  (0.9149959296417689, -0.44233041239025134)
  (0.9149959296417689, -0.6220770983026074)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (0.764760989649598, -0.909164298142755)
  (0.764760989649598, -1.46804479980734)
  (1.09530792932417, -1.43460964660762)
  (1.20470349481524, -0.340653991696946)
  (1.20470349481524, 0.218226509967615)
  (0.874156555140663, 0.184791356767894)
  (0.764760989649598, -0.909164298142755)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.8527882198115082, -0.6808926203122335)
  (1.1240182376178183, -0.6808926203122335)
  (1.1240182376178183, -0.48954160843927597)
  (0.8527882198115082, -0.48954160843927597)
  (0.8527882198115082, -0.6808926203122335)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (1.226526145812, -0.231598483774965)
  (1.22652614581199, 0.595201272436226)
  (0.786583640646383, 0.54653604590246)
  (0.617956509668863, -1.13973526387273)
  (0.617956509668863, -1.96653502008369)
  (1.0578990148345, -1.91786979354992)
  (1.226526145812, -0.231598483774965)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.784698957780285, -0.7063804113578739)
  (1.0750640767738906, -0.7063804113578739)
  (1.0750640767738906, -0.5043198977107385)
  (0.784698957780285, -0.5043198977107385)
  (0.784698957780285, -0.7063804113578739)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (1.28604627305562, -0.0508065165129705)
  (1.28604627305561, 1.19839631185699)
  (0.677476636912518, 1.12487678718561)
  (0.421303007660494, -1.43685950533463)
  (0.421303007660494, -2.68606233370428)
  (1.02987264380363, -2.61254280903289)
  (1.28604627305562, -0.0508065165129705)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.7140609166444976, -0.7121020461361469)
  (1.0246320870028167, -0.7121020461361469)
  (1.0246320870028167, -0.5005380380153659)
  (0.7140609166444976, -0.5005380380153659)
  (0.7140609166444976, -0.7121020461361469)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (0.152696774290067, -1.83290603746247)
  (0.152696774290067, -3.69428062791109)
  (1.01744003968518, -3.58061565814048)
  (1.40588590424132, 0.303842987420796)
  (1.40588590424132, 2.16521757786986)
  (0.541142638846251, 2.05155260809925)
  (0.152696774290067, -1.83290603746247)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.6428507120308828, -0.7036049870229895)
  (0.9745782832012801, -0.7036049870229895)
  (0.9745782832012801, -0.4839955195431415)
  (0.6428507120308828, -0.4839955195431415)
  (0.6428507120308828, -0.7036049870229895)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-0.216731288501042, -2.4006218767853)
  (-0.216731288501042, -5.14654254776789)
  (1.03645784145021, -4.96823585437409)
  (1.6224076620283, 0.891262351406865)
  (1.6224076620283, 3.63718302238989)
  (0.369218532077098, 3.4588763289961)
  (-0.216731288501042, -2.4006218767853)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.5724902133285839, -0.6857050321049143)
  (0.926178731246966, -0.6857050321049143)
  (0.926178731246966, -0.45830050052424487)
  (0.5724902133285839, -0.45830050052424487)
  (0.5724902133285839, -0.6857050321049143)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-0.731385543277831, -3.21535547224507)
  (-0.731385543277831, -7.29345816496984)
  (1.10775340725152, -7.01280162568897)
  (1.98612596426729, 1.7709239444688)
  (1.98612596426729, 5.84902663719358)
  (0.146987013737947, 5.56837009791271)
  (-0.731385543277831, -3.21535547224507)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.5039197101180924, -0.6620306568311631)
  (0.8803486811945415, -0.6620306568311631)
  (0.8803486811945415, -0.42513703766443084)
  (0.5039197101180924, -0.42513703766443084)
  (0.5039197101180924, -0.6620306568311631)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-1.46073135977482, -4.39340349345896)
  (-1.46073135977482, -10.5636310108625)
  (1.25678014777031, -10.1236256573403)
  (2.57102862798665, 3.01885914482306)
  (2.57102862798665, 9.18908666222662)
  (-0.146482879558475, 8.74908130870443)
  (-1.46073135977482, -4.39340349345896)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.5706309645241158, -0.5697397804548586)
  (0.7077128836724133, -0.5697397804548586)
  (0.7077128836724133, -0.44665551893215827)
  (0.5706309645241158, -0.44665551893215827)
  (0.5706309645241158, -0.5697397804548586)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-2.51709446086107, -6.11341690682214)
  (-2.51709446086107, -15.6183188492749)
  (1.5146655269004, -14.9330630940092)
  (3.48993729420931, 4.81965457907993)
  (3.48993729420931, 14.3245565215327)
  (-0.541822693552153, 13.639300766267)
  (-2.51709446086107, -6.11341690682214)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.5136569864786298, -0.531430017461147)
  (0.6630473317791974, -0.531430017461147)
  (0.6630473317791974, -0.41744607539390693)
  (0.5136569864786298, -0.41744607539390693)
  (0.5136569864786298, -0.531430017461147)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-4.07892634578856, -8.68544333206393)
  (-4.07892634578856, -23.5744199014376)
  (1.92810540928182, -22.5123630159944)
  (4.92239294636259, 7.43051235481332)
  (4.92239294636259, 22.3194889241869)
  (-1.08463880870779, 21.2574320387437)
  (-4.07892634578856, -8.68544333206393)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.46051398473251515, -0.4964265845072361)
  (0.6213027242398067, -0.4964265845072361)
  (0.6213027242398067, -0.38621236838418593)
  (0.46051398473251515, -0.38621236838418593)
  (0.46051398473251515, -0.4964265845072361)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-6.43636833593232, -12.4262704179285)
  (-6.43636833593232, -36.3900995019178)
  (2.56495095621883, -34.7475733266099)
  (7.15434183878128, 11.1463354990145)
  (7.15434183878128, 35.1101645830039)
  (-1.84697745336987, 33.467638407696)
  (-6.43636833593232, -12.4262704179285)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.41087132628179157, -0.4644529697032833)
  (0.582681487401388, -0.4644529697032833)
  (0.582681487401388, -0.3550152223389401)
  (0.41087132628179157, -0.3550152223389401)
  (0.41087132628179157, -0.4644529697032833)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-10.0753782861241, -17.702243488814)
  (-10.0753782861241, -57.7258371471229)
  (3.51533188858949, -55.1809677390287)
  (10.6653582970817, 16.3192963458931)
  (10.6653582970817, 56.3428900042021)
  (-2.92535187763192, 53.7980205961078)
  (-10.0753782861241, -17.702243488814)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.3644260293114632, -0.4353184705067951)
  (0.547179965167494, -0.4353184705067951)
  (0.547179965167494, -0.32479226976279224)
  (0.3644260293114632, -0.32479226976279224)
  (0.3644260293114632, -0.4353184705067951)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-15.8479620008364, -24.7137875791216)
  (-15.8479620008364, -94.900443483593)
  (4.89277458236938, -90.9314751908562)
  (16.2996472975019, 23.1372519604688)
  (16.2996472975019, 93.3239078649403)
  (-4.44108928570389, 89.3549395722034)
  (-15.8479620008364, -24.7137875791216)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.3208941822607836, -0.40884832681838984)
  (0.5147007381912148, -0.40884832681838984)
  (0.5147007381912148, -0.2960245598213543)
  (0.3208941822607836, -0.2960245598213543)
  (0.3208941822607836, -0.40884832681838984)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-25.3380063491957, -32.636146579462)
  (-25.3380063491957, -163.72232277894)
  (6.80960294914256, -157.456073735268)
  (25.6320380839959, 30.7682776132649)
  (25.6320380839959, 161.854453812743)
  (-6.51557121434236, 155.588204769071)
  (-25.3380063491957, -32.636146579462)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.28000934957894463, -0.38486583418900205)
  (0.48509828220907925, -0.38486583418900205)
  (0.48509828220907925, -0.268916163058924)
  (0.28000934957894463, -0.268916163058924)
  (0.28000934957894463, -0.38486583418900205)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-41.7102386270898, -36.3327695153007)
  (-41.7102386270898, -301.72164406616)
  (9.25980580610184, -291.637601847966)
  (41.8174834652703, 33.9391747437177)
  (41.8174834652703, 299.328049294576)
  (-9.15256096792138, 289.244007076383)
  (-41.7102386270898, -36.3327695153007)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.24152276616004442, -0.363190784002575)
  (0.4582066659031868, -0.363190784002575)
  (0.4582066659031868, -0.24334619751797007)
  (0.24152276616004442, -0.24334619751797007)
  (0.24152276616004442, -0.363190784002575)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-71.8824030337057, -13.2430981742233)
  (-71.8824030337057, -607.92465558493)
  (11.6453190586542, -591.24312267123)
  (71.7502883947279, 9.80657068950669)
  (71.7502883947279, 604.488128100213)
  (-11.7774336976321, 587.806595186513)
  (-71.8824030337057, -13.2430981742233)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.20520368775978698, -0.34364358640217296)
  (0.4338720461513898, -0.34364358640217296)
  (0.4338720461513898, -0.21954471142941387)
  (0.20520368775978698, -0.21954471142941387)
  (0.20520368775978698, -0.34364358640217296)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-132.674868592199, 135.387305645642)
  (-132.674868592199, -1381.9457077848)
  (10.9578228362348, -1353.28182183437)
  (132.199101204749, -140.869038149227)
  (132.199101204749, 1376.46397528121)
  (-11.4335902236844, 1347.80008933079)
  (-132.674868592199, 135.387305645642)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.17083932911956973, -0.3260535571320574)
  (0.41191757500844833, -0.3260535571320574)
  (0.41191757500844833, -0.19141593033939383)
  (0.17083932911956973, -0.19141593033939383)
  (0.17083932911956973, -0.3260535571320574)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m2_color, mark=none, fill=m2_color, fill opacity=0.5
] coordinates {
  (-270.869439370678, 884.244349008645)
  (-270.869439370678, -3703.88931209218)
  (-5.99546957373088, -3652.40634920687)
  (269.845498732871, -893.996666140863)
  (269.845498732871, 3694.13699495996)
  (4.9715289359225, 3642.65403207465)
  (-270.869439370678, 884.244349008645)
};

\addplot+[
  solid, m1_color, mark=none, fill=m1_color
] coordinates {
  (0.2082381056436471, -0.28339413344314346)
  (0.32468031175604084, -0.28339413344314346)
  (0.32468031175604084, -0.2033235983622052)
  (0.2082381056436471, -0.2033235983622052)
  (0.2082381056436471, -0.28339413344314346)
};
\coordinate (point) at (axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (spy point) at (axis cs:400,0.8);
\spy on (point) in node (spy) at (spy point);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\spy` does not enlarge pixels. -it does in fact "re-rendering the relevant part". A circle in spy will be round on all zoom levels. I believe the it is a rounding artefact. Could you produce a *Minimal* Working Example? Two plots are enough and no extra styles, colors, ...

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me *(and this deserves a closer look than I am giving it here)* that we reach the limits of TeX and TikZ here.

Since the axis environment measures `240x207 pt` by default (about `8.4 x 7.3 cm`). You have chosen a magnification of `100`, with the spy-in *(node that shows the magnification)* of `4cm by 3 cm`, i.e about `114pt by 85 pt`.
Being multiplied by 100, this node must therefore enlarge an area that measures on the original figure about one pt *(`115/100 pt and 85/100 pt`)*.

Hence the pixelization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) I guess spy works differently than I expected ~~ it would be nice if it wasn't just enlarging the existing pixels but re-rendering the relevant part of the graph at a new scale.